# qt dual-stack ipv4 & ipv6 application

Tags: qt, ipv6

I have a ipv4 client/server network application written in Qt (v4), which i have to port it in ipv6 (actually the client porting is the most important one), creating in this way a dual-stack ipv4 & ipv6 application.

i do not have any ipv6 network available so as to perform any tests.

i tried the following but with no success:

- find a tool that make ipv6 validation: there are not many, usually poorly documented and usually for C language
- create a local ipv6 network environment

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely create a local IPv6 network environment. A lot of things work the same in IPv6 as in IPv4, but a lot of other things are different. When developing applications that use IPv6 you should have some hands-on experience. You wouldn't expect someone who has never used IP to develop an application that uses IPv4, would you?

Some key differences:

- IPv6 addresses are written in hexadecimal
- IPv6 hosts will probably have multiple addresses

  - An IPv6 address that starts with `fe80:`
    This is the link-local address. Every IPv6 hosts has one for every interface it has. Link-local addresses exist on every link (ethernet segment, LAN) and they use the same address range on each LAN. It is therefore impossible to route them, but they are very useful when communicating only within the LAN.
  - One or more IPv6 addresses that start with something in the range `2000:` - `3fff:`
    These addresses are the globally routable addresses that you use for normal internet communication.
  - Zero or more IPv6 addresses that start with something in the range `fc00:` - `fdff:`
    These are Unique Local Addresses (ULA). They are routed within the house, building, organisation etc. They are not routed to the global internet so you cannot reach public services with them.
  - And of course maybe one or more IPv4 addresses
- NAT is (almost) never used with IPv6. ULA addresses are *not* NATed to a public address.

The best way to get experience is to use an IPv6 connection that is connected to the real IPv6 internet. If your ISP cannot provide you with IPv6 (they should these days, but many ISPs are still slacking) you can use a tunnel broker service like [SixXS](http://www.sixxs.net/) or [Hurricane Electric](http://www.tunnelbroker.net/). They will give you an IPv6-over-IPv4 tunnel with a /48 of addresses. That is enough for 65536 subnets of 2^64 hosts. More than enough for a development network :-)  SixXS has the benefit that they provide client software that can run behind a NAT router. Hurricane Electric has the benefit that the registration procedures are much easier.

Comment: I have both SixXS and HE tunnels. I've never waited more than 24 hours for a SixXS add/change. HE also seems to have a limit of 5 tunnels, and blocks port 25. SixXS doesn't block port 25 and allows as many tunnels as you want (provided you have the credits).